# Why is my form not posting to the pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I have been following [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/22) about using a form to create an article with 'tags'. I have replaced tags with categories. My articles 'belong to many' categories and my categories 'belong to many' articles. I have a form to create a new article but it only creates an entry in the `articles` table and not in the `article_category` pivot table.

I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ArticlesController.php line 77:
```

Call to a member function categories() on array

I think the problem is with fourth line in the `store` function. I can't find anyone with the same problem. That line is supposed to attach the article `id` to the category `ids` but it's not working. Grateful for any help.

My ArticlesController:

```
public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request)
{

     $article = $request->all();

    Article::create($article);

    $categoriesId = $request->input('categories');

    $article->categories()->attach($categoriesId);

    return redirect()->route('articles_path');

}
```

The namespaces:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use App\Day;
```

Routes:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController', [

    'names' => [

        'index' => 'articles_path',
        'show' => 'article_path',
        'edit' => 'articleEdit_path',
        'update' => 'articleUpdate_path',
        'create' => 'articleCreate_path',
        'store' => 'articleStore_path'
    ]

    ]);
```

Article Model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Article extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'article_category', 'category_id', 'article_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
protected $fillable = array('title', 'description', 'image', 'lat', 'lng');

}
```

Category Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'article_category', 'article_id', 'category_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

protected $fillable = array('name'); 
}
```

PivotTable:

```
Schema::create('article_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an error:

```
$article = $request->all();

Article::create($article);
```

Try this instead

```
$article = Article::create($request->all());
```

EDIT
Correct this relation in you article model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'article_category', 'article_id', 'category_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. If I change that I get this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`storelocatordb`.`article_category`, CONSTRAINT `article_category_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `article_category` (`article_id`, `category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (1, 48, 2015-10-27 20:11:10, 2015-10-27 20:11:10), (2, 48, 2015-10-27 20:11:10, 2015-10-27 20:11:10))

Comment: seems like the categories you are trying attach to the article arent created yet, is that possible? does category with id of 48 exist?

Comment: There's only three categories with ids of 1,2,3. ?

Comment: legend! Thanks. Works now. Are those stipulations after 'App\Category' necessary? and why? I'd be grateful for explanation/link to docs. Thanks again!

Comment: [Heres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) a link. They are not required if you stick to laravel conventions. The first paragraph in that link explains it but basically if you have lets say many to many for articles and categories, your pivot table should be named `article_category` (singular table names in alphabetical order) and the foreign keys on that table `article_id` and `category_id`. If everything is setup that way you do not need them, but if the names are different they need to be specified.